# Upgrade to 23.04 does not show or recognize Realtek Wifi Adapter

Tags: realtek, realtek-wireless

**PC recently upgraded to 23.04** and Mate desktop. Mate did not show the Wifi icon. Rebooted into Ubuntu Gnome desktop and that showed and attached to the USB Wifi adapter:

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 048d:5702 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:0047 Microsoft Corp. IntelliMouse Explorer 3.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8811AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:6364 Alcor Micro Corp. AU6477 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

After rebooting to Mate, it still didn't show up in networking or in the task bar. Though the hardware shows up:

```
sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for jimtek4: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 16
       serial: 18:c0:4d:3f:72:dc
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.2.0-39-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.8.244 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:37 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcd04000-fcd04fff memory:fcd00000-fcd03fff
```

And then Ubuntu showed an update was ready so I installed that. Wifi still not showing. So rebooted into Gnome...and then it was not showing there. So between the upgrade and no upgrade, the Wifi stopped working in Gnome and still doesn't work in Mate.

Anyone know how I can get Mate and Gnome to recognize the Realtek USB Wifi hardware again?

Thanks!

PS All the other links here on Askubuntu during search are older and don't seem to apply to 23.04.

Additional info:

```
Sudo apt-get -y install rtl8812au-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
rtl8812au-dkms is already the newest version (4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu20~23.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

As shown above.

Comment: Your device, 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8811AU, is not covered in any default Ubuntu kernel version. It has to be compiled from source code. Isn't that what you did in Gnome?

Comment: Yes, I installed the drivers for RTL8812au as that covers the 11au.

Comment: I don't know how to 'compile from source code' but I'll do a search for instructions. Do you have a link to the source code?

Comment: What is the response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe 8812au` ?

Comment: modprobe returns 'NULL'. modprobe for 8811au: sudo modprobe 8811au
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8811au not found in directory /lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic

Comment: Well, NONE (3) of the source codes are available any more. All of the terminal commands come back with 'no such file or directory'. The reason I wan't to use Realtek is because they're the only ones that seem to make high power 10 meter cable USB Wifi antennas and the other manufacturers don't. Well, except on occasion.

Comment: Well, RaLink is now offering one for $28. And I'm back on the road tomorrow (full time RV'er) so I'll not be able to order it until I'm settled again. And it looks very much like the RaLink device I bought several years ago that failed within a few weeks. But...it looks like it's time to finally give up on the Realtek products I already have and that seem to be everywhere on the online markets. If anyone has a work around I'd sure like to try it before I leave tomorrow. RV parks are notorious about having weak Wifi signals and I don't know anything about how it is at the new park I'm trying.

Comment: Did you try this? https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

Comment: Yes..."No such file or directory."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150319/discussion-between-chili555-and-jim-hitek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 0bda:a881 device is not an 8812au device; it is an 8821au. Let’s install the correct driver. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall git dkms build-essential bc
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708.git
cd 8821au-20210708
sudo sh install-driver.sh
```

Reboot. You should be all set.

Comment: This method worked and I'm now able to use my Realtek wifi adapters (USB type) with Ubuntu 23.04. Thanks to chili555.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour